# На чем лучше cделать браузерную игру 2d с знаниями C#, HTML, CSS

Tags: c#, html, разработка-игр

Как и чему нужно научиться что-бы делать простенькие браузерные игры, не мультиплейную.

Comment: Если браузерные, то нужно изучить JavaScript, особенно что касается WebSocket-ов.

Comment: а с моим знанием языков, вариантов мало? чем меньше учить разные языки тем лучше

Comment: Знание html и css недостаточны, а на c# игры (браузерные) не пишутся.

Comment: Почитайте Head First JavaScript. Там как раз описана разработка игры Морской бой. Будет с чего начать.

Comment: C# - Для браузерных игр вообще не нужен так-то. JS учить в любом случае, html&css - это считайте ваш базис, основа веба. В теории вы можете сделать статичную игрушку с кучей .html и .css файлов, но это очень муторно и скучно.

Comment: Вы же говорите, что игра "Браузерная". А в браузере работает только JavaScript так что без него никак. И не надо бояться новых языков. Все императивные языки очень похожи. Изучение каждого последующего языка идет гораздо проще, чем предыдущих. У JS конечно ООП принципиально другой, чем у линейки C++/C#/Java, привыкнуть надо будет.

Comment: Если не хотите учить JavaScript, то учите TypeScript. Он транскомпилируется в первый. Имеется его поддержка в Visual Studio.

Comment: А вообще. вполне можно написать браузерную игру практически без JS. Вся логика будет осуществляться на сервере. Так что учите ASP.NET web api.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov логику ещё и отрисовывать надо ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: для ознакомления с Typescript https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWSlv4KsAC06Q74KaGJ10RA/videos?sort=da&view=0&flow=grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тут смотрю, многие до сих пор в 90-х остались, когда вижу комментарии о том, что "на c# игры (браузерные) не пишутся".

Мне как Unity3d разработчику странно это слышать.

Игры под браузеры можно писать например на:

1. Unity3d. Язык используется C#. Можно собрать WevGL билд для браузеров.
2. Godot Engine (C#) позволяет [экспортировать WebGL билд](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/getting_started/workflow/export/exporting_for_web.html).
3. UrhoSharp (C#).

Answer (score 1):

Если не изменяет память то есть в юнити приложения для  браузера. Для этого по-моему достаточно совершенно знать c# так что дерзайте. Также есть asp.net что тоже приложения для браузера.